# Possible to set size of ram disk?

Tags: linux, centos, ramdisk, block-device, fedora

When I do

```
yum install MAKEDEV
MAKEDEV ram
fdisk -l /dev/ram
```

I get the that it is 16MB.

I am using MAKEDEV to get a block-device instead of tmpfs.

**Question**

Is it possible to set it to e.g. 1GB?

Comment: FYI, MAKEDEV is obsolete.  These days udev automatically creates the dev node when the driver is loaded.

Comment: @psusi Very interesting. How is that done with udev? When I boot I don't have `/dev/ram*` so doing `fdisk -l /dev/ram1` fails.

Comment: The kernel notifies udev when new devices are detected, and it creates the dev node.  Actually these days most distributions mount /dev as a devtmpfs, where the kernel internally automatically creates the node, and notifies udev for any additional processing.

Comment: @psusi I am not sure I understand. What would you type to get the ramdisk?

Comment: You don't have to type anything; as long as the ramdisk driver is loaded, the dev nodes exist.  If you had to create them with MAKEDEV then your udev/devtmpfs are not working correctly.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want a block device to access RAM (as opposed to using `malloc()` in your program)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block device driver for ramdisks has the size set at the time the driver loads, using the [`ramdisk_size=`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux/Documentation/blockdev/ramdisk.txt) parameter to specify the number of blocks (default blocksize = 1024 bytes, see `ramdisk_blocksize=` as well) to allocate to each ramdisk.  If you're loading it as a module, you can use that parameter when loading the module, otherwise if it's built into the kernel you'll have to boot that system as a kernel option.

It appears that at some point in 2.6 the ramdisk driver was changed so that [the first time you accessed it, the size of the ramdisk was set permanently](http://www.petroskoutoupis.com/lib/PetrosKoutoupis_EN42009.pdf) (rather than using the kernel option).

Regarding setting it to 1GB, I think it would be possible but once the ramdisk has been accessed it will occupy all 1GB in RAM and cannot be swapped out (unlike tmpfs which can swap if necessary).  There is also no way to unload the ramdisk and free the memory without a reboot.

Comment: When I do that, I can see in `dmesg` that the `ramdisk_size=` have been passed, but `/dev/ram*` all remains 16MB. I have tried to set it to 99MB on my 8GB ram server, and it is still 16MB.

Comment: @Sandra It may be that you'll need to use something like `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ram1 bs=1024 count=1000000` to allocate the full GB before you do anything else with the device.  Also, I'm not sure that I'd trust `fdisk` with the ramdisk since they're not partitionable normally.

Comment: Interesting idea. Didn't work however. `16777216 bytes (17 MB) copied, 0.051657 s, 325 MB/s`

Comment: The size is dynamically grown to fit as much as you write to it, like a file.  The ramdisk_size argument has been obsolete for years.  You also most certainly can unload the ramdisk module, or free a particular ramdisk memory with `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/ramX`

Comment: I'm not imagining that I have a freeramdisk command lying around.

Answer (score 4):

`mkfs -q /dev/ram1 X` where X is the size in KB. You'd want 1048576 for 1GB.

Comment: If I do that then I get `mkfs.ext2: Filesystem larger than apparent device size.` and it fails.

Comment: What about using ext4?

Comment: That is a warning, which prompts to whether to continue or not.  Say yes.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're more looking for something like `mount -t tmpfs -o size=1024m tmpfs mount_directory`

Comment: Updated OP. Using MAKEDEV because I want a block-device.